# How to update rows which have the max value per day?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, max

I have a MySQL table 'weather_data' which has the following fields:

- id
- temperature
- time
- max_temperature

It gets updated every 15 mins.
With the following MySQL command I can see the max temperature values per day:

```
SELECT MAX(temperature) FROM 'weather_data' GROUP BY DAY(time)
```

What I want is a MySQL command which goes through all my data, finds the max temperature per day and on each of that row updates the max_temperature field with the temperature on that time.
So if i have seven days of data I want to update 7 rows with max_temperature.

Is this possible?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: It is certainly possible, but is it is a good idea? You replicate one data point, the max temp on a day, over 95 rows. Why not make a new table, with one row per day, containing all the daily data? This practice is called 'normalization', see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you should store frequent temp and max temp in two separate tables.

Second, if you still prefer your schema, you can do something like this:

```
UPDATE weather_data
INNER JOIN  (
    SELECT MAX(temperature) as temperature, DAY(time) as date 
    FROM weather_data GROUP BY DAY(time)
) max_temp 
ON max_temp.date = DAY(time)
SET weather_data.max_temperature = max_temp.temperature
```

**Edit:**

If you would like to use the two tables approach, I'd suggest you have the following tables:

**weather_data:**

- id
- temperature
- time

**max_daily_temperature:**

- id
- max_temperature
- date

As for inserting: I think you already have taken care of weather_data, but for max_daily_temperature, it would be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO max_daily_temperature 
SELECT DATE(time), MAX(temperature) 
FROM weather_data 
WHERE DATE(time) = '2017-08-30'
```

and for update:

```
UPDATE max_daily_temperature 
SET max_temperature = (
    SELECT MAX(temperature)
    FROM weather_data 
    WHERE DATE(time) = '2017-08-30'
)
WHERE date = '2017-08-30'
```

If that is what you are looking fore, don't forget to mark the answer as a solution.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible that only the row with the max temperature gets this value (max_temperature)? With this code all rows of the day are filled with the same max_temperature value.

Comment: And thinking about it you may be right and a new table would make more sense. What would be the code to save these values in a new table called "weather_data_daily" with the values time and max_temperature? So one row for each each day.

Comment: Please check the update in my answer and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I think I prefer the solution to have a separate table.

As I already have a lot of data back in time, I need a query which inserts it for each day ever recorded (past). In the end I need one row per day.

The table should store:
1) time (complete time data, e.g. 2017-09-01 14:03:46)
2) max_temp. 
Could you help me with a adjusted code?

Comment: Anyone can help?